# Using VBA, I want to sum rows in a column (to be pasted elsewhere) but only if the adjacent cell (offset 0, -1) is positive

Tags: excel, vba

Here's the code I've written. I'm stuck!

```
Sub TotalSaving()
    
    Dim cell As Range, Rng As Range, A As Range, LastRow As Long, Sales As Worksheet, R As Range, P As Range, O As Range, N As Range
        Set Sales = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sales Output")
        LastRow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sales Output").Cells(Rows.Count, "Q").End(xlUp).Row
        Set Rng = Sheets("Sales Output").Range("Q6:Q" & LastRow)
        For Each cell In Rng
            Set P = cell.Offset(0, -1)
```

If q is positive, I want to count the corresponding value of P and then paste the sum of that column on another sheet.

Answer (score 1):

Use `WorksheetFunction.SumIfs`:

```
Set Sales = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sales Output")
With Sales
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "Q").End(xlUp).Row
    Set Rng = .Range("Q6:Q" & LastRow)
    
    Dim theSum As Double
    theSum = WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(Rng.Offset(0,-1), Rng, ">0")

    ' now write theSum to another sheet
End With
```